# Leaflet.markercluster with GeoJSON via AJAX

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, ajax

I am pretty new to this. Have found a similar question here but I have been unable to implement it in my own case. The markers show up just fine but no clustering happens.

```
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var lon = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
    var popupContent = "<h1>"+feature.properties.name+"</h1><p>"+feature.properties.address+"<br>"+feature.properties.city+"</p>";
    var marker;
    switch(feature.properties.icontype) {
        case "both":
            marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: both}).addTo(map).bindPopup(popupContent);
            break;
        case "soft":
            marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: soft}).addTo(map).bindPopup(popupContent);
            break;
        case "na":
            marker = L.circleMarker([lat, lon], na).addTo(map).bindPopup(popupContent);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(feature.properties.icontype+feature.properties.name);
    }
};

var clusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup();

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("map.geojson", {
    pointToLayer: onEachFeature
    //filter:
});     

geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function () {
    clusterLayer.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
});
```

This updated code seems to work:

```
    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var lon = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
    var popupContent = "<h1>"+feature.properties.name+"</h1><p>"+feature.properties.address+"<br>"+feature.properties.city+"</p>";
    var marker;
    switch(feature.properties.icontype) {
        case "both":
            marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: both}).addTo(geojsonLayer).bindPopup(popupContent);
            break;
        case "soft":
            marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: soft}).addTo(geojsonLayer).bindPopup(popupContent);
            break;
        case "na":
            marker = L.circleMarker([lat, lon], na).addTo(geojsonLayer).bindPopup(popupContent);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(feature.properties.icontype+feature.properties.name);
    }
};

var clusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup();

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("map.geojson", {
    pointToLayer: onEachFeature
    //filter:
});     

geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function () {
    clusterLayer.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
});
```

Comment: How is your problem different from the existing question. Kindly refer to it and explain.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by "add title and alt to each marker". Tooltip? You already have popup. Is it not working?

Comment: @Padmanabha yes, well that is my problem... I cannot see how it is different - It is just not working :-P But I should perhaps have explained better what I mean about not working... Added...

Comment: @TomazicM sorry... I was late and frustrated... I have removed that part as it just seems to just confuse. Was in fact 2 different questions: "Why is it not clustering?" was the main problem. 

The secondary question was regarding "title" and "alt" that is mentioned in leaflet documentation as recommended for accessibility for people using screen readers. I will search on for more info on adding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic problems in your code:

- for `pointToLayer` option function you are using function `function onEachFeature(feature, layer)` which is meant for `onEachFeature` option function; `pointToLayer` option function has `function pointToLayer(feature, latLng)` form and should return marker to be added to the GeoJSON layer;
- you are adding markers directly to the map, not to the GeoJSON layer.

Code should then look something like this:

```
function pointToLayer(feature, latLng) {
  var popupContent = "<h1>"+feature.properties.name+"</h1><p>"+feature.properties.address+"<br>"+feature.properties.city+"</p>";
  var marker;
  switch(feature.properties.icontype) {
    case "both":
      marker = L.marker(latLng, {icon: both}).bindPopup(popupContent);
      break;
    case "soft":
      marker = L.marker(latLng, {icon: soft}).bindPopup(popupContent);
      break;
    case "na":
      marker = L.circleMarker(latLng, na).bindPopup(popupContent);
      break;
    default:
      console.log(feature.properties.icontype + feature.properties.name);
  }
  return(marker)
};

var clusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup();

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("map.geojson", {
  pointToLayer: pointToLayer
});

geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function () {
  clusterLayer.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
  map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
});
```

Here is working JSFiddle (GeoJSON points are randomly generated with turf.js): https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/01fv945x/.

There's an additional problem in your code. In line

```
marker = L.circleMarker(latLng, na).bindPopup(popupContent);
```

you are referring to `na` variable which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thank you :-)

Didn't quite work: Using "pointToLayer: pointToLayer" puts no markers on the map for me. To start with I used "onEachFeature: onEachFeature" but that added both my special icon and the standard blue pin for each. The mix "pointToLayer: onEachFeature" comes from grabbing code of many different solutions in an attempt to get it working :-P This is my first time working on a map...

Just changing .addto(map) to .addto(geojsonLayer) worked though. I have updated the question above in case there is a better solution than my bodged code - if not I will accept your answer.

Comment: And na is defined but it is just variables for circleMarker, so I did not include it as is the case with the to special icons as well...

var na = {
    radius : 6,
    color  : '#FFC7E6',
    stroke: false,
    opacity: 1,
    fill: true,
    fillOpacity: 1
}

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. See edit answer with JSFiddle code.

Comment: Hmm... works now...